# On screen annotation software that lets you share annotations with friends?

Tags: annotations, saas

You know those apps that let you draw on your screen for presentations (or youtube tutorials).

Does something like that exist but sync'd across the web so you and your friends can both share your screens like a whiteboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.  There are features like this in many telecommunications apps but nothing that strictly serves this purpose.

I would check out flapdraw.